# Create a module that add text/image to a specific type nodes

Tags: nodes

So.
I need to create a module that add something like text, to all my nodes of type "Article" for example.

**I need a module that do:**
- Find the type of nodes "Article"
- And add a label that says "Made by me ..."
And everytime i see articles, they all have the normal fields (title,body,tag,image) and my label..

Its possible?

Comment: headerimage module? background_image module? you must provide more details of the functionality you'd like to achieve.

Comment: I need a module that do:
- Find the type of nodes "Article"
- And add a label that says "Made by me ..."

And everytime i see articles, they have the normal fields (title,body,tag,image) and my label..

Comment: Can't you just add this to a relevant theme template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various ways of doing this. Either edit your tpl file. Create a node--article.tpl.php in your theme folder (copy the syntax from node.tpl.php) and modify the code to add your desired label. If you need to print username then the global $user is available. Just define it as global and access username as `$user->name`.

Or you could use Panels module. It's very flexible and powerful.

For creating custom module to do this, there are various approaches. One good way is this:

In your custom `mymodule.module` file, use the [`hook_node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) like this:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
    if ($node->type=="article"){
        if ($view_mode == 'full'){
            $node->content['my_extra_content'] = array(
                 "#markup"=> '<strong>Made by me!</strong>',
                 "#weight"=> 100
              );  
           }
         return $node;
   }   
}
```

After this, `Made by me` should appear at the bottom of each node. If you want it to appear at the top, then just modify the weight and give it some negative value.

Comment: Then just use Panels Module. It's awesome. You will take some time to learn it but it'll offer you great rewards when you learn it.

Comment: Okay, I've modified the answer to give a solution using custom module. This should satisfy your needs. Kindly accept it as the solution if it does.